# Visual Studio 2017 takes to long to release the exe file?

Tags: visual-studio

I really hope that someone has a solution for this, this is so aggravating when your troubleshoot and you get this error "Unable to copy because it is being used by another process" which, is visual studio it self. I edit something that didn't come out right, try to recompile and I get this error message for close to a 30sec to 1 minute, before Visual Studio decide to let go of the exe file, so I can recompile my project so I can run again and see how it looks. I wast more time waiting, that it would be faster for me to delete the exe file, then compile, but, this is so stupid to do, I can't see a program as this, make a programmer wast time, this is suppose to make programming go faster. I'm not feeling it.

Comment: Not VS, it is the anti-malware you use that does this.  The flashy cr*pware doesn't deal well with an executable file appearing from seemingly no-where.  Make an exclusion for your project directories to get ahead.  Best to get rid of it completely however, use the one provided by the OS.  Or none, they are a solution to a non-existing problem these days.  Enjoy the speed-up.

Comment: Now you got me puzzel. I don't have a anti-malware, windows 7 Defense is dissable. I used Kaspersky total, check everything, and it doesn't have an anti-malware setting. Just found out with Kaspersky, the anti-malware is part of the anti-virus program. I have put the folder in excluding section. I will let you know it goes, thanks for your help.